# How To execute SQL Query in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, isqlquery

I have this SQL Query :

```
DECLARE @pageNo int=1
DECLARE @pageSize int=2

SELECT top 2 id,
Title,
Author,
NumberOfPages,
PublishedAt,
RowNumber
FROM 

(

SELECT top 2 id, Title, Author,
NumberOfPages,PublishedAt,
Row_Number() over (order by id desc) as RowNumber 
FROM Books 

)T
WHERE
T.RowNumber BETWEEN ((@pageNo-1)*@pageSize)+1 AND (@pageNo*@pageSize)
```

I want Execute this SQL Query with C# in ASP.NET core

I tried this Code :

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Books>>> GetBooks()
        {
          

  
      return await _context.Books.FromSqlRaw("Select * from Books where id = 2").ToListAsync();

           

        }
```

But this Code work only with Single Sql Query Line like last example

```
Select * from Books where id = 2
```

but when I try with Complex SQL Query with Multi lines is not Working

I hope your help

thank so much

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to achieve here. Your subquery will only return between 0 and 2 rows, so if the value of `@pageNo` is ever higher than 2, you'll get no rows. Also, if `@pageSize` is ever higher than `2` you'll still only get 2 rows.

Comment: this SQL Query is working perfect with other programming language for example with php was perfect working but I dont know how exeute Same query with ASP.net core

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the whole query in one line or use "+" or string builder to connect lines

```
var query ="DECLARE @pageNo int=1 DECLARE @pageSize int=2 SELECT top 2 id,..";

//or
 var query = "DECLARE @pageNo int=1 " +
             "DECLARE @pageSize int=2 " + 
             "SELECT top 2 id, " +
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best approach will be to write that query in text file & place it in your project then use this line of code to read text from that file

```
string queryText = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\yourpathhere\QueryTextFile.txt");
```

then use queryText variable